# Global component registration in Vue using <script>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component

I'm learning Vue and would like to use [vue-tabs](https://github.com/cristijora/vue-tabs).
The instructions for "installing" it globally are:

```
//in your app.js or similar file
//  import Vue from 'vue';  // Already available
import VueTabs from 'vue-nav-tabs';

Vue.component('tabs', Tabs);
Vue.component('tab', Tab);
```

However, Chrome 66 doesn't like the `import` statement. `VueTabs` is defined as a top-level `var` in `vue-tabs.js`:

`import VueTabs`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Some of the above might be incorrect. I'm still muddling my way through the basics of modern web development. So I'd appreciate a little higher-level description of whether I can do this or why not. It seems all the documents I find assume familiarity with pre-compilation and build steps.

I'd like to avoid using `npm`, `webpack` or `yarn`, etc, for the time being in order to focus on `Vue`. I like that `Vue` can be used by simply downloading `vue.js` into a local directory and then making it available using only a `<script>` tag.

I've tried using `<script https://...vue-tabs.js>` but haven't had any luck as with `Vue`.
Is it possible to use `vue-tabs` the same way, or is some kind of pre-compilation or build step going to be required?

Comment: "Chrome does not seem to like it" is not a very specific error message... Is there a error in the console? lf so post that error

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @TomRussel Have you tried to use `Vue.use(VueTabs);` in your script as it is a plugin I guess it will need to be intalled if not done automtically on browsers.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma "Uncaught ReferenceError: VueTabs is not defined"

Comment: @TomRussell try with `Vue.use(VueTabs)` as root object is assigned to VueTabs

Comment: The instructions you're following are intended for a project using a bundler like Webpack. I suggest you start out by using [vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/). Otherwise, you should be following [these installation instructions](https://cristijora.github.io/vue-tabs/#/?id=direct-script-include)

Comment: @Phil Thanks. So it's down the rabbit hole, then, I guess.

Comment: I'll admit, they're not very good instructions :)

Comment: @Phil I think it's just the damned DOM. Whatever happened to Flash? Oh, criminals...

Comment: You could use https://github.com/cristijora/vue-tabs/tree/master/dist directly.

Comment: @AndrewLi Really? That would be completely acceptable!

Comment: I think than you could change that script for your own purpose.

Comment: @AndrewLi Ugh. I think I'd need to first understand how it works with `Vue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be simple for you. If you don't want to use bundler like Webpack, then your HTML would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <vue-tabs>
            <v-tab title="First tab">
              First tab content
            </v-tab>

            <v-tab title="Second tab">
              Second tab content
            </v-tab>

            <v-tab title="Third tab">
              Third tab content
            </v-tab>
        </vue-tabs>
    </div>

    <!-- Load Vue.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <!-- Load Vue-Tabs -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-nav-tabs@0.5.7/dist/vue-tabs.js"></script>


    <!-- YOUR APPLICATION JS FILE -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new Vue({
            el: "#app"
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, you won't have to do any plugin installation or component registration as you are using it without ES modules or bundler. `VueTabs` will automatically install the plugin and register components when running as an old-school script.

Comment: @Harshall Patil Thanks. My page loads without errors, but still no tabs. Is there some kind of `vue-tabs` registration in `app.js`?

Comment: @TomRussell, Did you create your own component? In your own component, you will have to put the above tab generation code.

Comment: Harshal Patil Would you please list the contents of `app.js`?

Comment: @TomRussell, I have modified my answer and simplified it. Please refer to it.

Comment: @TomRussell, The solution is not really the recommended way if you are building a large scale Vue.js application; nevertheless, this will get you started.

Comment: Harshall Patil That did the trick. Thanks. I had a couple of things going on but it's nice to know it can be straightforward.

Comment: And then I dropped a couple of custom components I created between the `v-tab`s and it just worked. Very impressive and encouraging... Quite less painful (and, understandably, powerful) than the PolymerDart I've given up on trying to stay on top of.